# "PDF header signature not found." Twice reading the same file in C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm trying to read a file twice and I'm getting the error in the title. The code reads file first time without errors, but when I try to read the same file with another method again, I get **PDF header signature not found.** error. How can I read the file twice without error? Thanks.

```
public ActionResult Function(HttpPostedFileBase file, string l)
{
    try
    {
        var file2 = file;

        var ef = reader.ExtractReport(file.InputStream);
        var ef2 = reader.ExtractReportMultiple(file2.InputStream);
        //if (ef == null)

         _is = reader.ReadReport(ef, _is, out warning);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Here are my Extract report methods :

```
 public ExcelFile ExtractReport(Stream file)
 {
     var f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus { Serial = "1234567890" };
     f.OpenPdf(file);
     f.ExcelOptions.SingleSheet = true;
     if (f.PageCount <= 0) return null;
     var xls = f.ToExcel();
     if (xls == null) return null;

     var stream = new MemoryStream(xls);
     ExcelFile ef = ExcelFile.Load(stream, LoadOptions.XlsDefault);

     //var definedIndex = 10;
     //var columnSize = ef.Worksheets[0].GetUsedCellRange(true).LastColumnIndex;

     file.Close();
     f.ClosePdf();

     return ef;
 }

 public ExcelFile ExtractReportMultiple(Stream file)
 {
     var f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus { Serial = "1234567890" };
     f.OpenPdf(file);
     //f.ExcelOptions.SingleSheet = true;
     if (f.PageCount <= 0) return null;
     var xls = f.ToExcel();
     if (xls == null) return null;

     var stream = new MemoryStream(xls);
     ExcelFile ef = ExcelFile.Load(stream, LoadOptions.XlsDefault);

     //var definedIndex = 10;
     //var columnSize = ef.Worksheets[0].GetUsedCellRange(true).LastColumnIndex;

     file.Close();
     f.ClosePdf();

     return ef;
 }
```

Comment: Try to set the `Stream.Position` to 0 after the first use of the stream. Beware: *The stream must support seeking to get or set the position.Use the CanSeek property to determine whether the stream supports seeking.* Alternatively copy the Stream into a `MemoryStream` or into a file and access that copy. Furthermore, do not `Close` the stream in your `Extract*` methods but in the calling method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `ExtractReport` reads the `InputStream`'s content, thus shifting its 'current' position towards the end of the stream. You have to reset the [`Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position(v=vs.110).aspx) to the beginning in order to read the same stream again. Hence this might work:

```
var ef = reader.ExtractReport(file.InputStream);
file.InputStream.Position = 0;
var ef2 = reader.ExtractReportMultiple(file2.InputStream);
```

However, whether it will or won't work depends on the actual type of the `InputStream` objects and its capability to seek back to the beginning. See also the [`CanSeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Should it not be possible, your only option is to create a copy of the stream's content and work on the copy (e.g. using a [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) instance on a `byte[]`)